# Mac stuck on gray screen

Tags: macos, boot, macbook

I have a retina Macbook Pro with Mavericks. After the latest update, it is stuck on a gray screen during boot. After checking, it seems stuck when loading boot.efi. From the terminal, I see that boot.efi is locked. When I try to unlock it, I can't because it s a "read only system file". I can't sido either. Any clue on how to solve my problem? (I tried to reinstall without deleting partition, but it failed too)

Comment: I would suggest moving this to Ask Different

Answer (score 0):

What troubleshooting steps have you tried? Have you tried clearing the Nv ram? Also have you tried using diskutil to verify any issues. Also, you can also boot the machine into safe mode by holding the shift key. The machine will run a few tests while booting into safe mode. This could possible resolve the issue for you as well. Usually the grey screen is from a corrupt os.

In short

boot - hold command + option + p + r (let machine post 3 times)
boot - hold shift to bring machine into safe mode (does machine boot?)
boot - hold command + r - open diskutil - select disk - verify disk(does disk show errors?)

Comment: Hi I have tried all this. Yes, the file boot.efi is either corrupted or locked. Any clue on how to unlock it?